# issue in upgrading phpseclib in magento2

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento-2.0.5

I am working on a task that requires sftp connection and related functions. In magento phpseclib provide the same but they have not yet upgraded the library and it contains deprecated methods and constructors. I have downloaded the latest library and trying to use it with magento2.

What I have done is.. replaced the complete latest phpseclib with original phpseclib folders. But when I am trying to access the sftp class it keeps showing error that class SSH2 not found which is parent class for sftp.

I tried updating path n namespace but no luck.

Can anyone help me as I am stuck with this now.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than downloading the latest library, I would suggest to change the version of phpseclib in the root composer.json and run composer update. that way you will get the latest phpseclib.

BTW, the version has been updated in the develop branch, but is not yet in any of the patch releases. https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/composer.json#L47

Comment: Thanks Maddy! This would be the correct way of upgrading phpseclib, however I have found the alternate way of doing the same though needed to update one line in core composer file.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this in my own way,

Replaced latest Phpseclib in this path
\vendor\phpseclib\phpseclib\phpseclib\

and updated one line in core file (I know its not a good idea)
\vendor\composer\autoload_files.php around line# 74
from
$vendorDir . '/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php',
to
$vendorDir . '/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Crypt/Random.php',

Thats All. and my code is working!